# Insert into ObservableCollection per int comparison

Tags: c#

Say I have an ObservableCollection with two items:

```
0: dateUnix: 333
1: dateUnix: 222
```

Now I want to add a new Item:

```
dateUnix: 300
```

If I just were to use the `.add()` method, the item would get added at the end. But I want the item to be inserted between 222 and 300 since this would make the list sorted.

How do I insert an item at a certain position where it is less then item value after and higher then item value before?

Comment: Rather than _describing_ your code, can you _show_ your code with a [mre]?

Comment: just sort your list after inserting?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Or create a custom insert method that iterates through until it finds the right position to insert. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37208/sort-observablecollection-after-added-new-item

Comment: If your list is sorted, you can use binary search to find the position where the new items should be inserted

Comment: You can use a sorted collection type like SortedList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the top, I can think of two ways of doing this.
One would be, as was pointed out in the comments, to just insert and sort afterwards.

Another, more complex and more rewarding way would be to find the index of the first item greater or lesser than the one you're inserting and insert it at that index. Your list seems to be sorted in descending order, so it'd need to be the first lesser than.

You could achieve this using LINQ:

```cs
ObservableCollection<Int> collection = new ObservableCollection(new List<int>{333,222}); // == [333,222]
Int toInsert = 300;

collection.Insert(collection.IndexOf(collection.First(elem => elem < toInsert)), toInsert); // output == [333,300,222]
```

See this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XHz30j) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

If your collection is already sorted, just find the appropriate index to insert the element at (either via a linear or the faster binary search) and use `Insert` to store the element at that specific index.